# cv2.imshow crashing - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am reading an image and then displaying the image using cv2.imshow however this crashes my script with the below stack trace.

**Code**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import jsonify, request

from .repository import DocumentRepository
import cv2


class DocumentsResource(Resource):

    def __init__(self):

        self.document_repository = DocumentRepository()

    def post(self):

        img = cv2.imread('front.jpg')
        cv2.imshow('front.jpg', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Stack Trace**

> 2018-10-23 11:35:09.828 python3[47256:2814041] *** Assertion failure
>   in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1451/Foundation/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:361
>   2018-10-23 11:35:09.830 python3[47256:2814041] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to
>   invoke on the main thread.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff32116fcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff58db0c76 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff3211cd62 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff3421b300
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193     4
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff341a9e54
>   +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 469   5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2f668e56 -[NSApplication run] + 997   6   QtGui
>   0x000000010dc27c12
>   _ZN26QEventDispatcherMacPrivate22ensureNSAppInitializedEv + 128   7   QtGui                               0x000000010dc274ad
>   _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE
>   + 693     8   QtCore                              0x000000010d335d9f _ZN16QCoreApplication13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE
>   + 81  9   cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x00000001082677ef cvWaitKey + 207  10  cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
>   0x0000000108267e37 _ZN11GuiReceiver12createWindowE7QStringi + 263     11 
>   cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x0000000108267c6c cvNamedWindow +
>   540   12  cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x000000010826a3a1
>   _ZN11GuiReceiver9showImageE7QStringPv + 161   13  cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x000000010826a24c cvShowImage +
>   572   14  cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x000000010826298b
>   _ZN2cv6imshowERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayE + 475  15  cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so           0x0000000107853114
>   _ZL18pyopencv_cv_imshowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 404  16  Python                              0x0000000105e2fa4e _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 541   17  Python 
>   0x0000000105e2ef8b _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 44     18  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7ad7 call_function + 554    19  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb57 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5281    20  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   21  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   22  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f0a2 PyObject_Call + 137    23  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfebd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6151    24  Python
>   0x0000000105ec83ff _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1747    25  Python
>   0x0000000105e2eb8a _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441     26  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   27  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f0a2 PyObject_Call + 137    28  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfebd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6151    29  Python
>   0x0000000105ec83ff _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1747    30  Python
>   0x0000000105e2eb8a _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441     31  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfebd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6151    32  Python
>   0x0000000105ec83ff _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1747    33  Python
>   0x0000000105e2eb8a _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441     34  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfebd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6151    35  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   36  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    37  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    38  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   39  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    40  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    41  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   42  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    43  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    44  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   45  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   46  Python
>   0x0000000105e6df5b slot_tp_call + 71  47  Python
>   0x0000000105e2ede0 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 381   48  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b3b call_function + 654    49  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb57 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5281    50  Python
>   0x0000000105e3afe4 gen_send_ex + 242  51  Python
>   0x0000000105ebf28e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 3032    52  Python
>   0x0000000105ec83ff _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1747    53  Python
>   0x0000000105e2ef50 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225     54  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    55  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfbfd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5447    56  Python
>   0x0000000105ec83ff _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1747    57  Python
>   0x0000000105e2ef50 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225     58  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    59  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    60  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   61  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    62  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    63  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   64  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    65  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb57 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5281    66  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   67  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    68  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    69  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   70  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   71  Python
>   0x0000000105e6e96f slot_tp_init + 80  72  Python
>   0x0000000105e6b464 type_call + 178    73  Python
>   0x0000000105e2ede0 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 381   74  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b3b call_function + 654    75  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb57 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5281    76  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   77  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    78  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    79  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   80  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   81  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f0a2 PyObject_Call + 137    82  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfebd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6151    83  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   84  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    85  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    86  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   87  Python
>   0x0000000105ec7b42 call_function + 661    88  Python
>   0x0000000105ebfb3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5256    89  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f379 function_code_fastcall + 117   90  Python
>   0x0000000105e2fd21 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150   91  Python
>   0x0000000105e2f0a2 PyObject_Call + 137    92  Python
>   0x0000000105f2ecea t_bootstrap + 71   93  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff59c2b6c1 _pthread_body + 340    94  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff59c2b56d _pthread_body + 0  95  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff59c2ac5d thread_start + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating
>   with uncaught exception of type NSException

operating system
`macOS High Sierra version 10.13.3`

architecture (e.g. x86)
`x64`

opencv-python version
`*`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix two worlds. Flask (via Werkzeug underneath it) does some I/O-rewiring based on the assumption of running headless. It's possible that what you're seeing is what what looks like when you violate that assumption on a Mac.