# Flask - plt.imshow It does not make sense to draw an image when [NSGraphicsContext currentContext] is nil

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, opencv

I am thresholding an image and then i would like to display the image using plt.imshow.

```
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(threshold)
plt.show()
```

However i get the error

```
> It does not make sense to draw an image when [NSGraphicsContext
> `currentContext] is nil.  This is a programming error. Break on void
> _NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.`
```

Comment: xref https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12612

Comment: Duplicate (or rephrasing) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946974/cv2-imshow-crashing-libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-ty ? The answer I gave there applies here.